# Drawing audio waveform in winforms using OpenAL and VC++

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, fft, fftw, openal

I have a project on my studies about signal processing and I'm obliged to record sound from some source (e.g. microphone) and display the waveform and its FFT on two charts. I can't provide the functions displaying the buffer into chart and not stalling the whole program.

As I don't know C# yet, I chose Winforms under C++/CLI and OpenAL for sound capturing (0 experience in sound processing and this was recommended in few threads and the rest of my team is working with it so I'm kind of obliged to use it). I already have the code for chosing the sound device and recording sound into a buffer. I know that the while loop below is stalling the programm. I was thinking of using multi-thread but no idea how to use it. Or events...

This is code for capture start, inside some button event.

```
int go = 0;

const int SRATE = 44100;
const int SSIZE = 1024;
ALCdevice *hydromike;

ALbyte buffer[22050];
ALint sample;

some_event {
const char* diwajs = (msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(item)).c_str();
        hydromike = alcCaptureOpenDevice(diwajs, SRATE, AL_FORMAT_MONO16, SSIZE);
        alcCaptureStart(hydromike);

        buffering(); //function call for starting the buffer
}

void buffering(void)
{
while (go) {

    alcGetIntegerv(hydromike, ALC_CAPTURE_SAMPLES, (ALCsizei)sizeof(ALint), &sample);
    alcCaptureSamples(hydromike, (ALCvoid *)buffer, sample);

}
}

void drw(void)
{
chart1->Series["Bufor"]->Points->Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < 22050; i++)
{
    chart1->Series["Bufor"]->Points->AddXY(i, (int)buffer[i]);
}
}
```

I would like it to work like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q9cRZuosrOs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to complete the code, the problem was the UI and OpenAL threads were interfering with each other which resulted in freezing the app. Starting the buffering in another thread and setting a semaphore resolved the problem.

```
static Semaphore^ drawingSem = gcnew Semaphore(1, 1);
    Thread^ oThread;
alcCaptureStart(hydromike);

            oThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(buffering));
            oThread->Start();

static void buffering()
{
while (go) {
    drawingSem->WaitOne();
    alcGetIntegerv(hydromike, ALC_CAPTURE_SAMPLES, (ALCsizei)sizeof(ALint), buffer);

    alcCaptureSamples(hydromike, (ALCvoid *)buffer, sample*2);

    drawingSem->Release();


}
}

void MyForm::drw()
{

drawingSem->WaitOne();

chart1->Series["Bufor"]->Points->Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < bufsize; i++)
{
    chart1->Series["Bufor"]->Points->AddXY(i, (int)buffer[i]);
}
drawingSem->Release();
}

private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {

drw();

}
```